# How to convert List of Objects to Map and use the object's property as key?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of coin objects, I want to cast the list to the map. How can I use id's as a Map key?

```
class Coin {
  int id;
  String groupID;
  String symbol;
  int coinOrder;
  String fullName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `fromIterable` constructor for Map class. You can use it to convert a list to a map.

```
Map<int, Coin> map = Map.fromIterable(list, key: (item) => item.id, value: (item) => item);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter 3 >

```
final Map<int, Coin> coinMap = {
  for (var coin in coins)
    coin.id: coin
};
```